# How to enable slow log of AWS ElastiCache with terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

Can I enable slow log of AWS ElastiCache with Teraform?

Checked below page, but the parameter didn’t exist.
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/elasticache_cluster

I want to enable the logging setting of following image.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pklOU.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If its not directly supported by TF, then you can use [local-exec](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/resources/provisioners/local-exec.html) to run AWS CLI which will enable the logs for you.